# Элемент переменной высоты со скроллером

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь тех, кто разбирается в верстке.

У меня есть элемент с контентом (произвольной высоты, фиксированной ширины), он находится внутри элемента с `position:fixed`. Выше него находится шапка (элемент фиксированной высоты). Как сделать так, чтобы элемент был прикреплен к нижнему краю страницы и при этом отображал вертикальный скроллер, когда нужно?

[image]

Я пробовал сделать так, но получается, что либо он не притягивается к нижнему краю, либо растягивается на полную, игнорируя `overflow: auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [как-то так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/uCDRR/). Хотя такие вещи надо делать с учетом остальных стилей, которые могут и скорее всего, что будут влиять на данный блок.